# make a PHP variable a link

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Does anyone know how to make a link out of a php variable.  I want my php variable $LeagueLink to be a link to leaguehome with the name of the result of a mysql query.  Please help if you can....

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT League FROM League_Info WHERE User_ID = '$id'");
$result2 = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $result3 = $result2['League'];
    $LeagueLink = '<a href="home.com/test.php"><?=$result3?></a>';
```

Comment: security tip: use prepared statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$LeagueLink = "<a href=\"http://home.com/leaguehome.php\">$result3</a>";
```

To place variables directly into a string like above, it needs to be a double quote string (`"`), not a single quote string (`'`)

Or, if you're worried about carelessness-provoked errors, use string concatenation:

```
$LeagueLink = '<a href="http://home.com/leaguehome.php">' . $result3 . '</a>';
```

Comment: Please don't embed variables in strings, it is subject to errors if done carelessly.

Comment: `"<a href=\"home.com/leaguehome.php\">$result3</a>"` should be `"<a href=\"home.com/leaguehome.php\">".$result3."</a>"`

Comment: And when you're at it, if you don't need metacharacters in the string, change the double-quotes to single-quotes. And don't forget to put http:// before home.com, so the link works correctly.

Comment: @sgielen: I need the double quotes for embedding variables. I used single quotes on the concatenation alternative

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this

```
$LeagueLink = '<a href="home.com/leaguehome.php">'.$result3.'</a>';
```

Comment: what about with this... $LeagueLink = "<a href="leaguehome.php">$result3</a>";

Comment: You need to escape the double quotes. You can't put double quotes with double quotes. It is either `' "a" '` or `" 'a' "`